# What package provides the functionality to suggest which package to install when the user types an unknown command?

Tags: command-line, package-management

On Ubuntu 10.10 server when I type `htop` the result is simply:

`bash: htop: command not found`

I know that there is some software which I can install that tells me what I have to install that provides the (in this example `htop`) command.

What do I have to install?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[command-not-found](http://packages.ubuntu.com/command-not-found) [image: Install command-not-found] is what you are searching for :)

Comment: Thanks, this is it! :)
sudo apt-get install command-not-found

Comment: It won't take effect until you log out and log back in.  It won't automatically take effect in existing shell sessions.